# Parse object crashes while there is a key in the database

Tags: swift, parse-platform

So I am trying to change the background color for all rows in the chat, that a user has written himself. I do this by checking if the facebookID from the user, matches the facebookID on the message from the database.

But for some reason the `.valueForKey` on my Messages database keeps crashing.

```
var myUser:PFUser = PFUser.currentUser()!
var queryId = PFQuery(className: "Messages")

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.messageTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("messageCell") as! ChatTableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = messagesArray[indexPath.row]

    let getUser = myUser.valueForKey("facebookID")
    print(getUser)

    let getIDUser = queryId.valueForKey("facebookID")
    print(getIDUser)

    //if getUser == getIDUser {
        // make cell red
    //}
    return cell
}
```

This gives back the following in the console for `getIDUser`

```
reason: '[<PFQuery 0x133dadf10> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key facebookID.'
```

So the `getIDUser` returns an error, but I don't have a clue why since the database and key do exist.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried printing the result of `messageDB.obejectForKey("facebookID")` without casting it?

Comment: have you confirmed that `messageDB` is returning the object you expect?

Comment: @Russell Yes I have, it just gives back nil as well. When I print out the PFObject itself (the messageDB) it also gives back `<Messages: 0x1584eec50, objectId: new, localId: (null)> {
}`. It looks like it can't find the database? although it exists. BUT I can add  new messages to the database from the chat and save it... i find this very weird.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this

```
var messageDB:PFObject = PFObject(className:"Messages")
```

creates just new message object. And you indeed can add it to the database.

But to get you objects from store you have to perform query.
[Here are more info.](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#/c:objc(cs)PFQuery(im)findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:)

Comment: `cell.textLabel?.text = messagesArray[indexPath.row]
        let getUser = myUser.valueForKey("facebookID")
        print(getUser)
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
        let getIDUser = query.valueForKey("facebookID")
        print(getIDUser)
        return cell
    }`
Tried the following code, but it gives the error that the class is not key value coding compliant for the key facebookID

Comment: Also if I use the query, i'm basically filtering, while i still want to see all the results from the other query, just make the background a color if the facebookID from the Messages database is the same as the one from the PFUser.